# Can we use spark session object without explicitly creating it, if Submit a job by spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0, spark-submit

My question is very basic, My code is working fine. But I am not clear with these two points:

#### 1) when we submit any pyspark job using spark-submit do we need to create spark session object like this ?  in my script:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,SQLContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .appName("test") \
    .getOrCreate()
print(spark)
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
```

or i can directly access spark session object in my script with out creating it.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,SQLContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
print(spark) -- this can be ***sc*** not sure I am using spark-2
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
```

and if spark session object is available then how i can add config properties such as below or how to enable hive support.

```
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.enableHiveSupport() \
.config(conf=SparkConf().set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "2g")) \
.appName("test") \
.getOrCreate()
```

#### 2) Another approach is without using spark-submit I can write my python code to generate spark-session object and use it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926219/error-message-when-launching-pyspark-from-jupyter-notebook-on-windows)

My doubt is if i submit job using spark-submit and creating spark session object as mentioned above am i ending up creating two spark session ?

It would be very helpful if someone can explain me added advantage of using spark-submit over step 2 method. And do i need to create spark-session object if i invoke job using spark-submit from command line

Comment: I did not understand step 2. Can you explain that? How would you use that script?

Comment: like this probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926219/error-message-when-launching-pyspark-from-jupyter-notebook-on-windows

Comment: Hi, if below answer has solved your problem please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Comment: Hi, below answer has cleared few of my doubts, but i need to little bit more testing before i confirm.

Answer (score 4):

> When we submit any pySpark job using spark-submit do we need to create spark session object?

**Yes,** It is not needed only in case of shells.

> My doubt is if i submit job using spark-submit and creating spark
> session object as mentioned above **am I ending up creating two spark
> session** ?

### TL,DR; No

If we check the code you have written

```
spark = SparkSession \
  .builder \
  .enableHiveSupport() \
  .config(conf=SparkConf().set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "2g")) \
  .appName("test") \
  .getOrCreate()
```

Observe `getOrCreate()`, it will take care of at any time only one **SparkSession Object** (`spark`) exists.

I would recommend to create the context/session in local and makes code pure(as not depending on other our sources for object).